# How to create a ".htaccess" file like this?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to create an `.htaccess`, but we have some difficulties.

Here are examples of what I need, remembering that everything has to be on the same URL.

1) Whenever the user accesses the web site want add an `/home/` at the end of the URL.

```
Before: http://app.meusite.com/ 
After: http://app.meusite.com/home/
```

2) I want all URL are removed the `.php`.

```
Before: http://app.meusite.com/login.php
After: http://app.meusite.com/login/
```

3) I want all URLs that are as follows:

Before:

```
http://app.meusite.com/usuario-adicionar.php
http://app.meusite.com/usuario-editar.php
http://app.meusite.com/usuario-excluir.php
```

After:

```
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/adicionar/
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/editar/
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/excluir/
```

Just a note to be taken into account ...

Because the entire site be multilingual, must all accept the parameter page that will get `LANG = LANGUAGE` (Example: `lang = en_US`).

Then all the URLs above, must accept the GET vestment as well, and would like to stay as follows:

```
http://app.meusite.com/index.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/home/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/login.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/login/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-adicionar.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/adicionar/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-editar.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/editar/en_US/

http://app.meusite.com/usuario-excluir.php?lang=en_US
http://app.meusite.com/usuario/excluir/en_US/
```

I hope it to understand my question. And, can you help me to do it?

Below, my attempt:

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

RewriteRule ^home\/?(.*)\/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/?(.*)\/?$ $1.php?lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)\/?$ $1-$2.php?lang=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you remove the file extension you need to first make sure MultiViews is turned on. Also, you should include a canonical meta tag in your HTML head depicting what you want the link to look like if you’re worried that search engines might index your pages as duplicate content. It should look like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/post/post-title/">
```

To take off the file extension and add a forward slash you need this bit of code.

```
#turn on Multiviews if not already turned on
Options +MultiViews

#takes off the .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

#adds the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I learned this from here, and have used the code in my own .htaccess files successfully. I haven't yet been able to figure out how to handle the multilingual aspect of your question. I've never had that problem. But I'll do some research when I'm more well slept and get back here if I find anything useful. It feels like the answer is staring me in the face.

Once you get this fixed, don't forget to do your 301 redirects.